# store the output of dictionary given from the forloop in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to save (store) the output of the dictionary iterating with the help of for loop.

```
a_known_nodes = ['10.10.10.10', '100.10.10.10']

node_tree = {
    'device_type': 'texas',
    'ip': ' ',
    'username': 'lab',
    'password': 'lab',
}

a_s1_[i] = {}
for i in a_known_nodes:
    node_tree['ip'] = i
    print(a_s1_[i])
```

Expected output:

> a_s1_1 = {'device_type': 'texas', 'ip': '100.10.10.10', 'username': 'lab', 'password': 'lab'}
>   a_s1_2 = {'device_type': 'texas', 'ip': '10.10.10.10', 'username': 'lab', 'password': 'lab'}

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have the `variables` as a dict like this

```
a_known_nodes = ['10.10.10.10', '100.10.10.10']

node_tree = { 'device_type': 'texas', 'ip': ' ', 'username': 'lab', 'password': 'lab', }

result = {}
for i, node in enumerate(a_known_nodes):
    clone = dict(node_tree)
    clone['ip'] = node
    result[f"a_s1_{i}"] = clone

print(result)
```

Comment: Hi Seah,Thanks for the quick reply..i would like to save the output of each iterated dictionary in a separate variable(s) to access later, not as output of dictionaries in a list...

Comment: sorry I do not know what you wanted. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Seah, the output of the dictionary is assigned to a key a_s1_0 and a_s1_1....but i want that to be saved in a variable for every iteration like below.                       a_s1_1 = {'device_type': 'texas', 'ip': '100.10.10.10', 'username': 'lab', 'password': 'lab'}
a_s1_2 = {'device_type': 'texas', 'ip': '10.10.10.10', 'username': 'lab', 'password': 'lab'}